# Angular 5 "ng test" fails for application with BingMap

Tags: angular, unit-testing, bing-maps

I used a bing map loader for my angular 5 application to load the script.

used the following code

```
@Injectable()
export class MapLoaderService {

  private static promise;

  public static load() {
    if (!MapLoaderService.promise) {
      MapLoaderService.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        window['__onBingLoaded'] = (env) => {
          resolve('Bing Map API loaded');
        };

        const node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        node.async = true;
        node.defer = true;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
      });

      return MapLoaderService.promise;
    }
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

the application works fine with this loader service.
But after writing unit tests and when running **"ng test"**, It is showing the following error

> ERROR in src/app/bing-map/bing-map.component.ts(25,21): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'Microsoft'.

How can i load the bing map script for unit test ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, We need to add the bing map reference in test.ts file. /// <reference path="../node_modules/bingmaps/types/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All.d.ts" />